# Will colored shredded coconut show up in brownies?

Tags: coconut, brownies, coloring

My coworkers would like me to make faux "special" brownies.  The requirements are that the brownies look the part and still taste good but don't have any actual "herbs" in them.  My first thought was crushed dried mint leaves.  We also came up with colored coconut.  I'm going to try the mint leaves, but will the food coloring hold up on the coconut in the brownies?  Or would I be better off mixing undyed coconut into the brownie with some dyed coconut lightly mixed on top?  Or are there any other suggestions I could use?  I also thought of cat nip but that doesn't seem like it would taste good.

(I'm using code just in case I can't put the real word. LOL)

Comment: There is no official policy of regulating/deleting such content, but there are many people with strong opinion and they will possibly act through votes regardless of code or straight terms.

Comment: I also don't want to seem like I'm condoning anything. I'm just the resident baker for my office. I don't even know (or care) how they came up with the idea.

Comment: It is better for our format that updates only contain further info about the problem. If you found a solution, it's better to post it as an answer. It is also OK to accept your own answer, especially in cases like this where you made the experiment and now know best what works and what doesn't.

Comment: "Special" brownies just look like regular brownies. Done well, they just taste like regular brownies too. So, to make regular brownies look like "special" brownies, your best bet is to focus on decoration or packaging. Like [this](http://cdn01.dailycaller.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/pot-brownies-e1355108177488.png) or [this](http://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Rz0UzF_VXY7jqQPGVWn29A/l.jpg)

Comment: Special brownie's look & taste exactly like regular brownies. They're made with the oil from the cannabis not the leaves. Lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks rumtscho.  I wasn't sure if I should post as an answer or an edit.  I've edited to remove answer and place here.

Update: I ended up making two brownies. 
One 8X8 pan with 6 bags of mint tea stirred into it. It gave off a very earthy (and minty) smell and has a very earthy/herby taste (and minty too).  I doubt I'll make the mint ones again. 
The second one was a 9X13 pan with 2/3 of a bag of shredded coconut colored green. I put the coconut in a bowl and used gel food coloring.  I don't have a huge selection of colors, so I used green with a touch of brown. I could have used a little more brown so the green wasn't so bright. I mixed it in the coconut and then mixed most of it into the batter. The remainder went on top and lightly swirled into the batter. The effect was really good and amazingly the color didn't seep into the brownies. When you bite into them, the coconut maintained its green color. I didn't have any white chocolate to try the green white chocolate idea, but maybe next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Removed additional commentary out of an abundance of caution and respect, based on comment above.

I'd try dried and chopped mint in blondies (e.g., [KAF recipe](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/crazy-blonde-brownies-recipe)), which might taste and look good. Fresh mint might be too stringy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest colouring white chocolate green. Melt it and add green food colouring, then cool again and break it into chips. Add to the brownies and you should get the desired effect of brownies flecked with green. If you want to add an extra flavour you could add a couple of drops of peppermint oil to the chocolate too.